# Put search Icon inside text box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying  place search icon inside text box.But,Its displaying end of the row.

```
<div class="row input-group">
    <input class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5 col-xs-5 form-control" type="text" id="searchroleName" placeholder="Search here"  aria-describedby="basic-addon2"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon fa fa-search"  id="basic-addon2"></span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9dxryetu/

Its displaying like this
[image]

Comment: Did you even look [at the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputSuccess2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSuccess2"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `row` class from `input-group` div,
[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9dxryetu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Just checkout this jsFiddle. The problem was that you were not properly implementing `.row` include `.container-fluid` also to prevent -15px margin.

https://jsfiddle.net/fLLkwaqw

Comment: If this works for you. Mark this answer as correct.